# Как в уже существущем Nextjs проекте перенастроить роутинг?

Tags: nextjs

Имеется проект на nextjs, '13.4.9', при попытке в fsd архитектуру, он соотвественно ругается на папки внутри src - app и pages - потому что видимо создавался с опцией использовать src. Куда зашита эта опция или как ее переключить?

Я создал новый проект без использования src и при последующем ручном создании папки src - nextjs не кидает ошибки, видимо он не парсит src на наличие роутинга если изначальна опция отключена